# Search and replace using a custom utility to do the transformation

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I want to run a custom replacement utility for values matching a regular expression. This means for every match of a regular expression, call a custom utility with the characters comprising the match. The output of the custom utility replaces the original characters.

Can illustrate using `factor`, but this case should not be considered exhaustive, for example may want to include expressions with `$`, `%`, and arithmetic operators:

```
$ factor 230
230: 2 5 23
```

Using this utility and invoking it for all integers in the input, this is an example input and output:

```
$ [code] <<< 'Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes.'
Given these numbers: 27: 3 3 3, 13: 13, 230: 2 5 23, and 19: 19, it is evident which are primes.
```

I thought this might work, but it looks like it's trying to interpret the input directly. Using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/factor \1/ge' <<< 'Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes.'
sh: 1: Given: not found
```

Obviously I'm not understanding what the `e` flag does. I tried doing this in `awk`:

```
$ awk '{r = gensub(/([0-9]+)/, system("factor \\1"), "g"); print r}' <<< 'Given the numbers with factors: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes.'
1:
Given the numbers with factors: 0, 0, 0, and 0, it is evident which are primes.
```

I'm not sure where the `1:` comes from, but it's apparent that it's printing just the return code from `system`. There doesn't appear to be a way to capture the standard output from a command in `awk`.

Is what I'm asking for possible in the core utilities?

Comment: try https://shellcheck.net to see what it flags. Generally don't use dbl-quotes for `sed` cmds. And some seds require escaping the parens for named buffers to work.  `'/\([0-9]+\)/factor \1/ge`. That'a a weird error message, and not from `sed`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - confirmed same results with single quotes; `shellcheck` indicates no issues.

Comment: Also, its not clear from your code. Even if we get it to work, it will only insert the word "factor" before each number. Your Q seems to want to actually run a function on each of the found words. No version of `sed` that I know of will do that for you. You'll need to use a higher level language.  I think it could be done in awk, and definitely python, perl and others. Good luck.

Comment: *"Is what I'm asking for possible in sed, perl, or awk?"* . Just re-read this. Yes possible in perl and awk. Not in sed ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - That's too bad, it would seem to be a really powerful and useful feature for `sed`.

Comment: IMHO, you're really holding yourself back, by trying to stick to one (really limited) tool. Anything beyond simple `s/s/r/` replacements should be done in a real language designed with text processing in mind (yes, sed is definitely only for text processing ;-) ). What I always found was, that even though I mastered `sed`, `csh` for my current job scope, when I moved up, I found that I could spend hours trying to find a super advanced usage of `csh` OR I could just write it in 5 minutes using a bourne shell deriviative (bash, zsh, ksh). Just saying ;-) ....

Comment: The same would be true for `sed` vs `awk` and or `perl` and now `python`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1` in your awk command output comes from you printing the return code from `system()`. `system()` returns the exit status of the command it calls, not the output from the command - that just goes to stdout. Also, with the syntax you used system() is called before gensub() so you're calling factor with the literal string `\\1`.

The correct syntax to do what you tried to do with GNU awk:

```
awk '{r = gensub(/([0-9]+)/, system("factor \\1"), "g"); print r}'
```

is this which will work with any awk:

```
$ awk '{
    head = ""
    while ( match($0,/[0-9]+/) ) {
        cmd = "factor " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        ret = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : cmd " failed" )
        close(cmd)
        head = head substr($0,1,RSTART-1) ret
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $0 = head $0
    print
}' <<< 'Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes.'
Given these numbers: 27: 3 3 3, 13: 13, 230: 2 5 23, and 19: 19, it is evident which are primes.
```

and with GNU awk for the 4th arg to split() it could be written as:

```
$ awk '{
    n = split($0,others,/[0-9]+/,nums)
    $0 = ""
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        cmd = "factor " nums[i]
        ret = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : cmd " failed" )
        close(cmd)
        $0 = $0 others[i] ret
    }
    $0 = $0 others[n]
    print
}' <<< 'Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes.'
Given these numbers: 27: 3 3 3, 13: 13, 230: 2 5 23, and 19: 19, it is evident which are primes.
```

Comment: Thank you. Yours is the clearest answer so far. All the answers work more-or-less in the specific case, but I'm finding issues when trying to modify the regular expressions in all of them. For example, to recognize numbers written in assembly languages: `$FFFF`, `&7777` `%1111`, the `$` or the `&` messes up, and because all the quoting possibilities are "used up" there's no way to escape them and make the regex and/or the evaluation work. I think I'm just going to bite the bullet and write a parser in `re2c`.

Comment: If you have to deal with "numbers" that are something other than digits then obviously you should have included that in your sample input/output. It'd almost certainly have been trivial for us to include whatever cases you have to deal with but at this point everyone's put effort into helping you solve the problem you said you had so YMV with getting people to revisit it now as everyone hates [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691)

Comment: I was debating how much detail to put in the question. If there's too much, it looks "well defined" and people suspect it's a homework question. Because I was asking a generic question, with the generic requirement of _for every match of a regular expression, call a custom utility with the characters comprising the match_ I was hoping people would code for the generic case and not for the specific illustration.

Comment: That's fine if you knew how to write the regular expression you really cared about but you got the generic answer (replace the regexp `[0-9]+` in my scripts with your real regexp) to your generic question and now you say you can't use it for some reason and have to go write a parser in some tool. As long as you're happy I guess...

Answer (score 3):

To replace numbers with the output of `factor` on each

```
echo "Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes." | 
    perl -wnE'say s{([0-9]+)}{$f=qx(factor $1); chomp $f; $f}egr'
```

This uses `/e` modifier to evaluate the replacement side as code. The `qx` runs the command and returns its output, from which the newline is removed  by `chomp`. With `/g` it keeps going through the string to replace all numbers. See below for explanations.

With the `/r` modifier the substitution operator `s///` returns the modified string.

Output:

```
Given these numbers: 27: 3 3 3, 13: 13, 230: 2 5 23, and 19: 19, it is evident which are primes.
```

Read on for explanations, in the context of other approaches.

---

*Original post*

To extract numbers from lines of input and call a program on each on it, for example

```
echo "Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes."
    | perl -wnE'say "Result: ", join(",", map { qx(factor $_) } /([0-9]+)/g)'
```

The regex's match operator in the *list [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context)*<sup>†</sup> returns matches, while the [`/g` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) makes it find all of them. That list is passed to [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), which applies the code in its body to each element and returns the resulting list.
The [`qx` is the operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) form of backticks, which returns the output of the command, what seems to be what you wanted.

I'll leave formatting of the output to you, here the list is [join](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)-ed by `,` and prepended by a string.

If the input lines are in a file

```
perl -wnE'say "Result: ", join(",", map { qx(factor $_) } /([0-9]+)/g)' file
```

For more involved processing you can assign the list of matches to an array 
and then do what you please with it

```
perl -wnE'@n = /([0-9]+)/g; for (@n) { say "process $_" }' file
```

This processes one line of input at a time.

More simply, to call the program `factor` on each number as it is matched

```
perl -wnE'while (/([0-9]+)/g) { say qx(factor $1) }' file
```

The regex in the `while` condition keeps looking for matches in each iteration, continuing from the position of the previous match, by the virtue of `/g` modifier in *scalar context*<sup>†</sup>. Inside the body you can then do what you need with each captured match which is in `$1`.

---

<sup>†</sup>   The list context in the first use of `/g`
is imposed since `map` takes a list as input. In the second one the context is scalar since the code in the `while` condition is evaluated to a scalar.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I can't hardcode the output. It has to do a search and replace into the input.

Comment: @YiminRong Moved the solution which directly replaces numbers in the string to the top (and corrected typos in it)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for replacing the text within the string:

```
perl -MList::Util=pairs -E '($m,$s) = ($_->key,$_->value) and $ARGV[0] =~ s/$m/$s/ for pairs map {$_, qx/factor $_/} $ARGV[0] =~ /(\d+)/g; say $ARGV[0]' \
'Given these numbers: 27, 13, 230, and 19, it is evident which are primes'
```

Note that the output of `factor` has a newline at the end.

Comment: Thank you. So far yours seems to be the best answer.

Comment: best because it's so clear that you can tell by reading it that it doesn't contain any bugs, (e.g. would it work if the input contained regexp or backreference metacharacters?) and/or you would find it easiest to enhance later when you have to build upon it and/or it's most portable and/or most efficient and/or best by some other measure?

Comment: It should work on any string. But I grant that it's not pretty. It would definitely be more readable as a script, in which case I would also be using strict syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/$(factor &)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Surround all numbers by an inline function call, then surround the entire string by double quotes and evaluate that string using `echo`.

Comment: Thank you. The input may have `$` and other special characters in it, so that might cause issues.